# A pair of non-conjugate subgroups: a simple proof

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, orthogonal-groups, conjugacy-classes

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Set
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma_1 &=
\left\{
I_{6},
\;
\gamma_1:=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0 \\
&&0&1\\
&&1&0\\
&&&&1 \\
&&&&&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\gamma_2:=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0 \\
&&1&&&\\
&&&1&&\\
&&&&0&1\\
&&&&1&0 
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\gamma_3:=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
1&&&\\
&1& \\
&&0&1&\\
&&1&0\\
&&&&0&1&\\
&&&&1&0
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\right\},
\\
%
%
%
\Gamma_2 &=
\left\{
I_{6},
\; 
\gamma_1':=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0 \\
&&0&1\\
&&1&0\\
&&&&1\\
&&&&&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\gamma_2':=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&&1&\\
&0&&1 \\
1&&0&\\
&1&&0\\
&&&&1\\
&&&&&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),
\;
\gamma_3':=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&&&1\\
&0&1 \\
&1&0\\
1&&&0\\
&&&&1\\
&&&&&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\right\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I was able to prove that $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are not conjugate in the special orthogonal group $SO(6)$, that is, there is no $a\in SO(6)$ such that $a\Gamma_1a^{-1}=\Gamma_2$. However, the proof is quite involved.

> Do you have a simple argument to prove that $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$
> are not conjugate in $SO(6)$?

My interest in the pair of group is that they almost conjugate, that is, there is a bijection between the groups that preserves $SO(6)$-conjugacy classes. This follows easily since the eigenvalues of any non-trivial element are $+1$ with multiplicity $4$ and $-1$ with multiplicity $2$.

Comment: What is $G$ in "$G$-conjugacy classes"?  Is it $\operatorname{SO}(6)$?

Comment: LSpice: yes, it was a typo. I meant $G=SO(6)$. Thanks!

Comment: kindasorta: it is well known that the groups are not conjugate in $S_6$. In fact, the corresponding pair in $S_6$ was the first pair of almost-conjugate groups constructed by Gassmann.

Comment: @LSpice thanks for pointing that out. I deleted my comment since it contained incorrect information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the elements $g = \dfrac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{\oplus3}$ and $h = \dfrac1 2\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ in $\operatorname{SO}(6)$ satisfy $g^{-1}\gamma_i g = h^{-1}\gamma_i'h$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$.

If I understand correctly, one example of almost-conjugate subgroups is the pair of subgroups of $\operatorname{PGL}_4(\mathbb C)$ generated, first, by the images of $\gamma \mathrel{:=} \operatorname{diag}(1, -1, 1, -1)$ and $\operatorname{antidiag}(1, 1)^{\oplus2}$; and, second, by the images of $\gamma$ and $\operatorname{diag}(1, 1, -1, -1)$.

Comment: involved proofs are usually incorrect...

Comment: @emiliocba, I edited in an example of non-conjugate, almost-conjugate subgroups of matrix groups, if I understood the terminology correctly.